# Morris.js Bar Graph in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, morris.js

I am using Morris.js graphs to display my MySQL data. Unfortunately the graphs are not visible at all. I have followed a simple tutorial and still nothing happens. What am I doing wrong in the code? I am assuming that the `data` format under `Morris.Bar` code should be different. What should the format be?

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "host", "", "_data");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Datas";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$chart_data = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $chart_data .= "{ ID:'".$row["ID"]."', Name:".$row["Name"].", Wrongs:".$row["Wrongs"].", Rights:".$row["Rights"].", Percentage:".$row["Percentage"].", Age:".$row["Age"]."}, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | How to use Morris.js chart with PHP & Mysql</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">MySQL</h2>
   <h3 align="center">Data</h3>   
   <br /><br />
   <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


    <script>
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'chart',
  data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
  xkey: 'ID',
  ykeys: ['Wrongs', 'Rights'],
  labels: ['Wrongs', 'Rights'],
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there actual data in the database? Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: There are no errors at all and yes the database is filled.

Comment: All I am receiving are the texts "MySQL" and "Data".

Comment: Could be this $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0); What is the output from this if you echo it?

Comment: The $chart_data is not an array and just a string. if you pass it in substr function it will only return the first word in this case which is "{". That's the problem in my opinion.

Comment: Ah no it is returning me all the values from the table. So it serves as an array itself.

Comment: I did that and i get the values from my database. I don't think thats the problem. Maybe it is under ```Morris.Bar```

Comment: Any reason why it won't show? Even if the database is filled and echo works.

Comment: Not really. Everything else looks fine. Try posting the var dump here. Maybe that helps.

Comment: It is something to do with ```data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],``` It is somehow not able to showcase the data.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, all I had to add was a one line function before calling `Morris.Bar`
The function is to check if the document is ready before proceeding:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'chart',
  data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
  xkey: 'ID',
  ykeys: ['Wrongs', 'Rights'],
  labels: ['Wrongs', 'Rights'],
});
});
</script>
```